# Azure SQL Server client for Mac OS X that does not require Java

Tags: osx, sql-server

Is there a Microsoft SQL Server client that runs on Mac OS that does not require Java? If there is more than one, which would you recommend?

Besides one that runs the usual queries, I would also like one that helps export data out of SQL server and into MySQL or Postgres. And of course price is also a consideration.